# $xz+yt\gt\frac{1}{2}(x+y)(z+t)$

Tags: inequality

Suppose $y\gt x$ and $t\gt z$ , then

$$xz+yt\gt\frac{1}{2}(x+y)(z+t)$$

How can I prove this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$y-x>0,\ t-z>0\Rightarrow (y-x)(t-z)>0\Rightarrow xz+yt>yz+xt\Rightarrow 2(xz+yt)>(x+y)(z+t)$

Answer (score 0):

If $y\gt x, t\gt z$ then

$$\frac 12(x-y)(t-z)\lt 0\\
\implies \frac 12(xt-yt-xz+yz)+xz+yt\lt xz+yt\\
\implies \frac 12(xt+yt+xz+yz)\lt xz+yt\\
\implies \frac 12(x+y)(z+t)\lt xz+yt$$